# Is there a way to export a Mura calendar?

Tags: icalendar, mura

Is there any way to export *just* the calendar? (I have a client that wants to transition to WP but is only concerned about the calendar.)

Comment: How are your database query skills? All of the page content data is stored in a database. So you should be able to extract what you need from there.

Comment: Hey, Miguel-F -- My client doesn't have direct access to the database and is only able to provide me with an export using the Mura tools. So I've got a big dump of XML files, but no way to really determine where the calendar details are.